# Google-script GmailApp search for label or nouserlabels

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'm trying to create a script that will allow me to search for e-mails and their attachments by label name or no user labels. If in searchForLabels is more than one entry, the script does not work.

```
function searchLabels(){

  //if there is more than one entry here, the script does not work
  var searchForLabels = 
      [
        'has:nouserlabels',
        'label:Test1'
      ];

  for (var l = 0; l < searchForLabels.length; l++) {

    var threads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox newer_than:4d' + searchForLabels);  
    var msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
    Logger.log(searchForLabels)

    if (searchForLabels == 'has:nouserlabels'){    
      for (var i = 0 ; i < msgs.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < msgs[i].length; j++) {
          var message = msgs[i][j];
          var from = message.getFrom();
          var subject = message.getSubject();
          var getAttachments = message.getAttachments();
          var body = message.getPlainBody();
          var getTo = message.getTo();
          Logger.log(subject)

          for (var k = 0; k < getAttachments.length; k++) {
            var attachment = getAttachments[k];
            var content = attachment.getContentType();

            //rest of my code
          } 
        }      
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made two little changes over your code. After testing it, it works as you requested.

The first one is on the `var threads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox newer_than:4d ' + searchForLabels[l]);` line. I used the `l` iterator on the `searchForLabels` array. I used it because, reading the context of the line, it seems appropriate. This change will iterate over the tags. Forgive me if this was not your original intention.

The second change is required for the script to work. I commented out the `if (searchForLabels == 'has:nouserlabels') {`, because it will never be `true` if the `searchForLabels` array has more than one element. This is the error that you detected. Please, notice how the correspondent `}` is commented out too.

This is the final and working version of the script:

```
function searchLabels() {
  //if there is more than one entry here, the script does not work
  var searchForLabels = [
    'has:nouserlabels',
    'label:Test1'
  ];
  for (var l = 0; l < searchForLabels.length; l++) {
    var threads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox newer_than:4d ' + searchForLabels[l]);
    var msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
    Logger.log(searchForLabels)
    //if (searchForLabels == 'has:nouserlabels') {
      for (var i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < msgs[i].length; j++) {
          var message = msgs[i][j];
          var from = message.getFrom();
          var subject = message.getSubject();
          var getAttachments = message.getAttachments();
          var body = message.getPlainBody();
          var getTo = message.getTo();
          Logger.log(subject)
          for (var k = 0; k < getAttachments.length; k++) {
            var attachment = getAttachments[k];
            var content = attachment.getContentType();
            //rest of my code
          }
        }
      }
    //}
  }
}
```

I want to add that you can use the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference) on Apps Script to accomplish your request in a simple way. In particular, you can use [Users.messages LIST](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) to list all the mails with your selected tags. There you can see an [example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#examples_1) (click over `JavaScript`) where a function is ready to make a search. To enable this API you shall follow the guide for [activating advanced services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services). Do not hesitate to ask for more clarifications or any question.

Comment: Jacques-Guzel Heron - thanks for the answer. Based on your suggestion I have corrected my code

Answer (score -1):

```
function searchLabels() {
  var searchForLabels = [
    'has:nouserlabels',
    'label:Test1'
  ];
  for (var l = 0; l < searchForLabels.length; l++) {
    var threads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox newer_than:4d ' + searchForLabels[l]);
    var msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
    Logger.log(searchForLabels)
    if (searchForLabels[l] == 'has:nouserlabels') { //limits emails to those without tag
    //if (searchForLabels[l] == 'label:Test1') { //or to those with tag
      for (var i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < msgs[i].length; j++) {
          var message = msgs[i][j];
          var from = message.getFrom();
          var subject = message.getSubject();
          var getAttachments = message.getAttachments();
          var body = message.getPlainBody();
          var getTo = message.getTo();
          Logger.log(subject)
          for (var k = 0; k < getAttachments.length; k++) {
            var attachment = getAttachments[k];
            var content = attachment.getContentType();
            //rest of my code
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation of how this works, please?

Comment: Which part needs explanation? Generally, the code allows you to search for emails that don't have any of my labels, then get attachment from message;
getAttachment is taken from [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-attachment)